# How to tell CMake to put non-c files in the executable directory?

Tags: c, file, cmake, clion

I'm trying to write a little webserver in C, using CLion. I do have some HTML files representing 404 error pages, default pages, etc. These files are in a folder inside the main project, and when I need to refer to them in the C source, the path I use is `./pages/page.html`.

The program works fine if I compile and run it manually inside the main project directory, but when I try to use CLion to run the program, the HTML files are not found and the program crashes, because the executable is not inside the directory where the `pages` folder is. What I would like to do is to configure CMake so that the directory `./pages` will be copied and placed inside the folder where the executable will be put into.

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting, I think of a quick but ugly solution. To write a `POST_BUILD` command.

Comment: I hope the duplicate question helps.

Comment: @iharob Thank you, the solution in the duplicate worked